# Ubuntu 20.04 booted in cli mode

Tags: boot, command-line, dual-boot

So today I opened my pc and when I booted into ubuntu it opened in a terminal login, I entered my credentials and now I am stuck in the cli, how can I fix this?

Comment: Who knows what you did to achieve this result?

Comment: I did nothing, last time it was normal and i was just coding in vsc nothing else

Comment: try ```sudo systemctl restart gdm3```

Comment: Ok and then what?